# SQL Server 2008, limit the row_number() over(partiton by)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database table that looks like this

```
customer type || transaction date || amount
            a ||   June 27 2016   || $10
```

I'd like to add a row number order by transaction date partitioned by customer type.

```
select 
    customertype, 
    row_number() over(partition by customertype order by transactiondate desc) as 'rowNum'
from 
    myDB
```

One problem with the query is that I get this:

```
customer type || transaction date || amount || rowNum
           A  ||       Jan 1 2016 || $20    || 1
           A  ||       Jan 1 2016 || $40    || 2
```

The problem is I don't want to assign different `rowNum` for different amounts. 
Both rows should have rowNum = 1 regardless of the amount.

Another problem is I'd like to show the most recent three transactions.
I know one way which is to add row number for every transaction, but my db contains data from way back 1990s. It's just too big.

So, I want to limit the search by the most recent 3 transactions without making outer query.

My idea is that I don't have that many customer types so maybe I can trace back 3 past transactions for each customertype, which I believe is much lighter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. replace `row_number` with `dense_rank`

   ```
   select  customertype,
           dense_rank() over (partition by customertype 
                              order by transactiondate desc) as 'rowNum'
   from  myDB
   ```
2. You can probably assume that you had at least 3 transactions, let's say, in the last 30 days?
   Use `WHERE` to choose the transaction from the last 30 days and then use row_number with descending order to find the last 3 transactions.

Comment: for 2, no, I can't assume that the last 3 transactions were made in the last 30 days. It could be almost 5 years ago too. I really can't use the time period contraint in the sql.

Comment: So there is no chance your database is too big to query the full history.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a query like this:

```
SELECT myDB.*, t.rn
FROM myDB
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         customertype, transactiondate,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY customertype, transactiondate) rn
     FROM myDB
     GROUP BY
         customertype, transactiondate) t
ON myDB.customertype = t.customertype AND myDB.transactiondate = t.transactiondate;
```

Not tested ;).